# How can we add DLLs to an Install Shield "build" on the command line/at build time?

Tags: installshield

We would like to add DLLs to an install based on some external command

(We want to reuse a script/install shield configuration multiple times from a command line.  We have a program that will be localized and the localization just requires an additional DLL be added to the target directory.  Because of the additional size of the DLL(s) we do not want to put them all in one installer.  )

So for example we want to programmatically build the following:

- Just an English installer
- A specific language installer (add one named DLL to the install listed above)
- ALL languages installer (gets all DLLs in a particular directory - we don;t want to have to specify the name)

If there is a better way to do this then please speak up - we don't care how it is done.  WE are new to Install Shield (And not very impressed frankly).

Does the command line perhaps take multiple "scripts" or sources in order to combine pieces?  We're not fluent enough with the tool to understand the paradigms that are commonly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into the concept of release flags and product configurations.  You can create a single installer project that builds a variety of different views to meet all of your requirements.  I have one customer that I did this for where I build 57 install configurations from one installer baseline to support all of his variation points.